# How to pass proporty of a class define in model as URL action paramter

Tags: c#, exception, razor, model-view-controller, url-action

I received the following error message:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member
>   declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member
>   assignment, simple name or member access.

from the following line:

```
<a href="@Url.Action((string)ViewBag.RequeryAction, (string)ViewBag.Vertical, new {  filters.size ="medium"})
```

How can I pass the filter properties to the controller?

---

I have defined the following types:

```
class Filters {
     string Layout;
  `  bool onlyBlack
}

class Image {
    Filters filter;
    double height;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a property name with a dot in it. `filter.size` is not a valid name.

Use this instead:

```
<a href="@Url.Action((string)ViewBag.RequeryAction, (string)ViewBag.Vertical, new { filtersSize ="medium"})
```

Comment: it didnt get bind to the size property inside filters as the controller is expecting object of type image